# Print the content of a json file

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new with react native and I am trying to load a Json data containing a categories list and then trying to display their names. This is my code

```
import categories from '../Categories.json';

render () {
return (
<View>
{categories.map(ctegory => <Text> category.name </Text>)}
</View>
```

I get this error

```
undefined is not a function (near '..._Categories2.default.map...')
```

Do you have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: I am trying to do it with react native, not javascript alone, so no.

Comment: react is a javascript library so Yes. It works just as same. Please try the suggestions before saying _no_

Comment: You have a typo in your code.  {categories.map(ctegory => <Text> category.name </Text>)}

Comment: Still the same problem. undefined is not a function. I am not able to call .map on my object

Comment: show your `categories.json` and how you export the json from it.